# Careers: Allow multiple apps/software with same link

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I think the current design where, if you try to add an application to your apps/software list with the same link as another, it'll just update the already-added entry is a bit too opinionated. I understand that it's likely there to prevent common errors, but for some cases, there's actually a good reason to do this. Think project umbrellas where the individual projects don't have any particular page of their own (other than their GitHub page, which is not usable in the apps/software list) but instead are all listed on the umbrella page. This is particularly common for developer-oriented project umbrellas where developers are really expected to just go from the umbrella page to the GitHub page of the project they're interested in to learn more.

Answer (score 4):

If all of your apps, software, etc are all listed out on a single page, then you should describe a *single* app as such. You get a description box, so you should use it to explain shortly all the apps you have available at this location.

The problem you're facing here is you're **adding titles that don't describe the link**. When you click on a project, you expect to go to a page *specific to that project*, not a general page covering everything. Even worse, when you open multiple links for different projects, you become confused why they all opened the same exact link.

Yes, it's nice to see all the projects you've worked on, but no one enjoys opening a bunch of links that are the same only to find out all the projects are on that one page. You're far better off listing a single title that covers all your projects and explaining the different ones in the description. That way they *know what to expect* when they get there. They know beforehand that this is an umbrella for multiple projects, and that they should browse around to check out all the different projects you have to offer there. Generally, a "company name" of sorts is a great way to summarize the projects.

---

To make it a little more clear, adding multiple projects that all go to the same link is like me telling you that I've written answers to all of these FAQs, and linking them all to the search results, like so:

> - [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfaq%5D+user%3Ame+is%3Aanswer)
> - [Is it acceptable to write a thank you in a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfaq%5D+user%3Ame+is%3Aanswer)
> - [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfaq%5D+user%3Ame+is%3Aanswer)

That's not very helpful to anyone, now is it? If you're really concerned about adding separate links, you should focus more on actually providing separate pages for each project in some way, so you do have separate links for each one. A better way:

> - [Answers I've Written to Frequently Asked Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfaq%5D+user%3Ame+is%3Aanswer)
>     I've provided several answers to FAQs, such as explaining what serial voting is, discussing the etiquette of saying thanks, and outlining how to read your reputation history.

This link text and description accurately describes exactly what I should expect to find on the page I'm about to visit: a list of my answers, including the ones I've already described.